# Ubuntu server 22.04 general protection fault

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04

I got a new mini pc to be my selfhost server and at times it hangs without crashing.
Meaning I can still ssh but containers/docker for example are unresponsive.
sudo reboot also pretty much hangs since it waits forever to kill stuff, so all I can do is to physically reboot the machine.

Here is what journalctl had to say about it the last time it happened:

```
kernel: general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0xffdfd5e688d2e150: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI  
kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 651408 Comm: 5 Not tainted 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu  
kernel: Hardware name: AZW Gemini M/Gemini M, BIOS 5.13 11/13/2020  
kernel: RIP: 0010:rmqueue+0x44a/0xbb0  
kernel: Code: 04 49 8b 46 10 49 01 db 49 39 c3 0f 84 33 01 00 00 48 be 00 01 00 00 00 00 ad de 49 8b 46 10 48 8b 08 48 8b 50 08 4c 8d 40 f8 <48> 89 51 08 48 89 0a 48 89 30 48 83 c6 22 48 89 70 08 41 83 fd 1f  
kernel: RSP: 0000:ffffabf78101bb60 EFLAGS: 00010097  
kernel: RAX: ffffd5e688c3b2c8 RBX: ffff9b85f7db6580 RCX: ffdfd5e688d2e148  
kernel: RDX: ffff9b85f7db65a0 RSI: dead000000000100 RDI: ffff9b85fffd6b80  
kernel: RBP: ffffabf78101bc30 R08: ffffd5e688c3b2c0 R09: 0000000000000001  
kernel: R10: 0000000000000293 R11: ffff9b85f7db65a0 R12: ffff9b85fffd6b80  
kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9b85f7db6590 R15: 000000000002d588  
kernel: FS:  00007f1eacd0c740(0000) GS:ffff9b85f7d80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000  
kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033  
kernel: CR2: 000055d38ad66000 CR3: 000000010eb0e000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0  
kernel: Call Trace:  
kernel:  <TASK>  
kernel:  ? __mod_memcg_lruvec_state+0x63/0xe0  
kernel:  ? xas_load+0x17/0xd0  
kernel:  get_page_from_freelist+0xd1/0x520  
kernel:  __alloc_pages+0x17e/0x330  
kernel:  alloc_pages_vma+0x9d/0x390  
kernel:  do_fault+0x69/0x2e0  
kernel:  handle_pte_fault+0x1cd/0x240  
kernel:  __handle_mm_fault+0x3c7/0x700  
kernel:  handle_mm_fault+0xd8/0x2c0  
kernel:  do_user_addr_fault+0x1c9/0x670  
kernel:  exc_page_fault+0x77/0x170  
kernel:  asm_exc_page_fault+0x26/0x30  
kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f1eacf75340  
kernel: Code: 00 00 49 8b 14 24 41 8b 44 24 08 4c 01 d2 48 83 f8 26 74 0a 48 83 f8 08 0f 85 ca 1a 00 00 49 8b 44 24 10 49 83 c4 18 4c 01 d0 <48> 89 02 4c 39 e3 77 d0 49 8b 83 d0 01 00 00 48 89 85 60 ff ff ff  
kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffed18130a0 EFLAGS: 00010206  
kernel: RAX: 000055d38a8d89c0 RBX: 000055d38a67df60 RCX: 000055d38a43b910  
kernel: RDX: 000055d38ad66000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 000055d38a67e008  
kernel: RBP: 00007ffed18131a0 R08: 000055d38a67ec08 R09: 0000000000000000  
kernel: R10: 000055d38a43b000 R11: 00007f1eacf9f2e0 R12: 000055d38a53e7f0  
kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007f1eacf9f2e0 R15: 000055d38a43b000  
kernel:  </TASK>  
kernel: Modules linked in: tls veth xt_nat xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo nft_counter xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc cmac nls_utf8 cifs cifs_arc4 cifs_md4 fscache netfs overlay intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci_intel_apl snd_sof_intel_hda_common mei_hdcp >  
kernel:  iwlmvm kvm snd_hda_codec btusb mac80211 btrtl rapl btbcm snd_hda_core btintel intel_cstate libarc4 bluetooth snd_hwdep rtsx_usb_ms ecdh_generic iwlwifi ecc memstick snd_pcm mei_me snd_timer serio_raw snd cfg80211 soundcore mei mac_hid sch_fq_codel dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone mtd efi_pstore>  
kernel: ---[ end trace 3b7862dbac1d2138 ]---  
kernel: RIP: 0010:rmqueue+0x44a/0xbb0  
kernel: Code: 04 49 8b 46 10 49 01 db 49 39 c3 0f 84 33 01 00 00 48 be 00 01 00 00 00 00 ad de 49 8b 46 10 48 8b 08 48 8b 50 08 4c 8d 40 f8 <48> 89 51 08 48 89 0a 48 89 30 48 83 c6 22 48 89 70 08 41 83 fd 1f  
kernel: RSP: 0000:ffffabf78101bb60 EFLAGS: 00010097  
kernel: RAX: ffffd5e688c3b2c8 RBX: ffff9b85f7db6580 RCX: ffdfd5e688d2e148  
kernel: RDX: ffff9b85f7db65a0 RSI: dead000000000100 RDI: ffff9b85fffd6b80  
kernel: RBP: ffffabf78101bc30 R08: ffffd5e688c3b2c0 R09: 0000000000000001  
kernel: R10: 0000000000000293 R11: ffff9b85f7db65a0 R12: ffff9b85fffd6b80  
kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9b85f7db6590 R15: 000000000002d588  
kernel: FS:  00007f1eacd0c740(0000) GS:ffff9b85f7d80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000  
kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033  
kernel: CR2: 000055d38ad66000 CR3: 000000010eb0e000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: This is typically a hardware error - maybe memory. I had a similar problem, and solved it by replacing the RAM with ECC server memory. Also [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409091/general-protection-fault-what-to-do-about-it). Replacing the RAM would be a good thing to try.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Oof, that can't be good. Time to memtest i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, as @ArturMeinild pointed out, after a couple of memtest86 runs a few errors appeared.

rip ram